# Valgrind: Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I'm getting a few Valgrind errors concerning Unitialised values and Conditional Jumps. Here is my Valgrind output

```
==28124== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==28124==    at 0x4C2E0E9: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28124==    by 0x400AA7: append_character (in /home/i)
==28124==    by 0x401319: refresh_address (in /home/)
==28124==    by 0x402067: main (in /home/)
==28124==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==28124==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28124==    by 0x4012C0: refresh_address (in /home/)
==28124==    by 0x402067: main (in /home/)
==28124== 
==28124== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==28124==    at 0x4C2E0E9: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28124==    by 0x400AA7: append_character (in /home/)
==28124==    by 0x40134F: refresh_address (in /home/)
==28124==    by 0x402067: main (in /home/)
==28124==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==28124==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28124==    by 0x4012E0: refresh_address (in /home/)
==28124==    by 0x402067: main (in /home/)
==28124== 
==28124== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==28124==    at 0x400987: binary_decimal (in /home/)
==28124==    by 0x401377: refresh_address (in /home/)
==28124==    by 0x402067: main (in /home/)
==28124==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==28124==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28124==    by 0x4012E0: refresh_address (in /home/)
==28124==    by 0x402067: main (in /home/)
```

Here is my 'append_character' function. Pretty simple stuff.

```
void append_character(char* str, char ch){
    int len = strlen(str) + 1;
    str[len] = ch;
    str[len + 1] = '\0';
}
```

And here is my 'refresh_address' function. Where the problems seem to arise.

```
void refresh_address(int memLength, address_info *mem, char *address){
     int j = 0;
     mem -> numSetIndexBits = calculate_set_index_bits();
     mem -> numBlockOffsetBits = calculate_block_offset_bits();
     mem -> numTagBits = calculate_num_tag_bits(memLength, mem);
     mem -> tag = malloc(mem -> numSetIndexBits * sizeof(char) + 1);
     mem -> setIndex = malloc(mem -> numSetIndexBits * sizeof(char) + 1);

     for(j = 0; j < mem -> numTagBits; ++j){
        append_character(mem -> tag, address[j]);
     }

     while (j < (mem -> numSetIndexBits + mem -> numTagBits)) {
        append_character(mem -> setIndex, address[j]);
        j++;
     }    
     mem -> decimalIndex = binary_decimal(mem -> setIndex);
}
```

I can't think of what I'm doing wrong. Any idea what is causing this? Thanks for the help!

Edit: address_info *mem is initialized in main with the following code where address_info is a struct.

```
 while(fgets(buffer, 130, stdin)){
    if(sscanf(buffer, "%c:%d:%d", &accessTypes[i], &accessSize[i], &address[i]) != EOF) {
        memory = malloc(sizeof(address_info));
        init_address_info(memory);

        if (accessTypes[i] == 'W') {
                memory -> accessType = "W";
        }
        else {
                memory -> accessType = "R";
        }
        binary_add = binary_address(address[i]);
        mem_length = strlen(binary_add);
        memory -> numSetIndexBits = calculate_set_index_bits();
        refresh_address(mem_length, memory, binary_add); /*Calls malloc for the memory's set index and tag in this function*/
        ++i;
        free(binary_add);
        free(memory);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough information.

Comment: Please tag either C or C++ according to which sort of compiler you are using ; not both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious thing that jumps out at me is that you allocate memory for `mem->tag` and then immediately start appending things to it... but you never ever initialized it (sound familiar?).  This means that you are calling `strlen()` on the `char *` that you pass in, which refers to `mem->tag`, but it is uninitialized.  That's just asking for trouble and it is very realistic that your `strlen` call and subsequent append of the character and then a null will exceed your allocation off of the heap.

Comment: In my `init_address_info` call in main, I initialize `mem->tag = NULL;` I was under the impression that would suffice?

Comment: Gosh, I'm such an idiot. I thought I was initializing it already - but clearly I wasn't. I fixed the issue by use calloc instead

    `mem -> tag = calloc(100, mem -> numSetIndexBits * sizeof(char));`
    `mem -> setIndex = calloc(100, mem -> numSetIndexBits * sizeof(char));`

Comment: That will work. :)  Something to file into your memory for the future, when using `calloc` don't assume that the variable or structure type recognizes nulls as "empty."  In the case of a character string, you're fine, but on some other architectures and with some data types this would *not* be a safe assumption. :)