# Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation linked list

Tags: c, valgrind

I'm creating a method to load a file into a linked list. It works, but valgrind keeps giving me the error below. I'm trying to allocate memory for `new_node`.

I've seen a number of posts, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101845/valgrind-uninitialised-value-was-created-by-a-heap-allocation) that suggests using `calloc`, but it did not work [the load function stopped working]. I tried to initialize `struct node * new_node = NULL;` but got same problem, getting this error running valgrind:

```
==1960==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==1960==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==1960==    by 0x40112F: load (dictionary.c:85)
==1960==    by 0x400964: main (speller.c:40)
==1960==
```

Might someone have some safe ways to allocate memory so that I don't have an uninitialized variable?

```
//HERE IS STRUCTURE OF HASHTABLE:


#include "dictionary.h"



// Represents number of buckets in a hash table
#define N 26

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

int countWords = 0;

//prototypes
void printNumber(); //struct node *start);

// Represents a hash table
// an array of nodes
node *hashtable[N];
node *head;
```

Below is actual section with the error

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // Initialize hash table
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        hashtable[i] = NULL;
    }

    // Open dictionary
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        unload();
        return false;
    }

    // Buffer for a word
    char word[LENGTH + 1];

    // Insert words into hash table

 while (fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
    {
        // TODO
        countWords++;
        //create node
        struct node * new_node;
        //create a new node anytime new word
        //create a node and allocate memory for each word

//THIS IS LINE 85 BELOW BY THE WAY!
        new_node = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
        //if empty...
        if (new_node == NULL)
        {
            //speller quits
            unload();
            return false;
        }

        //copy word into node
        strcpy(new_node->word, word);

        //get location of word to go in hashtable by hashing value
        int index = hash(word);

        //put word in that location if nothing there
        if(hashtable[index] == NULL)
        {
            //QUESTION: is head in array or at end of linked-list?
            hashtable[index] = new_node;
        }

        //we need to link it to last node
        else
        {
          // struct node * head = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(node));
           head = hashtable[index];
           new_node -> next = head->next; //I may not be assigning this correct
           head->next = new_node;

        }
    }
    //printNumber();//header);
   // free(new_node);
    // Close dictionary
    fclose(file);

    // Indicate success
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you attach the code for the node structure.  I suspect you have a problem with the strcpy().  You allocate space for new_node, but not for new_node->word.  As a result you are most likely writing to unallocated memory.

Comment: Now that I see the definition the strcpy is not causing the crash.

Comment: Thanks so much. It's not crashing thankfully. I'm just getting an error with valgrind about the initialized value

Comment: Aren't there other `valgrind` errors messages? That's only telling you where the memory was allocated. There should be other messages telling you where the uninitialised values are used.

Comment: You need to set `new_node->next = NULL` in the `if(hashtable[index] == NULL)` case. Or just do it all the time. And `calloc` is a good way to do it. If you say you get errors after changing to `calloc` then it means you have other bugs in your code (it's not calloc's fault). I would suggest using `calloc` and then debugging whatever errors arise from that (if you don't then those errors will likely crop up later when you least want it to regardless of whether you chnage to `calloc` or not).

Comment: Unrelated, but initialising `*new_node = NULL;` and checking, but not casting, the result of `malloc()`/`calloc()` is a good idea.

Comment: Ok thanks everyone.... I'm getting this error on Valgrind in addition:  ```==7819== 8,010,184 bytes in 143,039 blocks are indirectly lost in loss record 1 of 2
==7819==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==7819==    by 0x40112F: load (dictionary.c:87)
==7819==    by 0x400964: main (speller.c:40)
==7819== 
==7819== 8,011,640 (1,456 direct, 8,010,184 indirect) bytes in ```  I'll work on it!

Comment: You can't `free(new_node)` in `load()`, but every allocated block of memory must be `free`'d somewhere (i.e. when you are finished using it). If `unload()` loops through `hashtable[]`/linked-list and frees the memory, call it before `main()` returns. You might also want to then set the pointers equal to `NULL`, to prevent "dangling pointers" to unallocated memory addresses.